# Correct date time according to device location india or usa

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I want to get current time according to my iPhone device I am using code which is giving me yesterday time.
My code is

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateStart = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())


let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let strDate = Date().description(with: Locale.current) //dateFormatter.string(from: dateStart)
```

print("date Start ***** (dateStart)")

By this I am getting a response :

date Start ***** 2018-02-14 18:30:00 +0000

Can anyone help me how can I get correct time today is 15-02-2018 18:00

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current iPhone device timezone date and time from UTC-5 timezone date and time iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504843/get-current-iphone-device-timezone-date-and-time-from-utc-5-timezone-date-and-ti)

Comment: What you are getting from just print Date () ?

Comment: use : `Date().description(with: Locale(identifier: NSTimeZone.local.identifier))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do I use it? Can you please share an example of it?

Comment: Why there is downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateStart = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // Feb 15, 2018 at 12:00 AM"
print(dateStart) // 2018-02-14 18:30:00 +0000

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "UTC" }
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: localTimeZoneAbbreviation)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateStart)
print(newDate) //  2018-02-15 00:00
```

**Update :**

```
// Current Time  
dateStart = Date() 
newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateStart)
print(newDate) //  2018-02-15 22:30
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is giving me a correct date but not correct time. It always gave me 00:00.

Comment: Because `calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())` is 2018-02-14 18:30:00 +0000 means Feb 15, 2018 at 12:00 AM which is in 24hr 00:00

Comment: In 24 hr `calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())` start of the always start with 00:00.

Comment: Ok but I need current correct time too. How do I get it ?

Comment: `let dateStart = Date()`  to get current time in 2018-02-15 11:30 formate. Ans updated for current time